# Wine staging version order

Tags: wine, version

Are WINE `x.y-staging` versions older or newer than `x.y` release? [wine-staging.com](https://wine-staging.com/) says

> Wine Staging is maintained as a set of patches which has to be applied on top of the corresponding Wine development version.

but that applies to both `x.y` being the base the staging patches are applied on or the predecessor of `x.y` which will become `x.y` after patches from `-staging` have been merged or posponed for the release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The x.y-staging and x.y development version are developed in parallel. The general idea is that simple bug fixes are added directly in the development version and more risky stuff is added in the Wine Staging first. Since the x.y-staging version usually contains more features and bug fixes than the x.y development release, it could probably be called "newer". On the other hand, the staging versions are also more risky because of the experimental nature of those changes.

There is no fixed point in time when certain features from Wine Staging are merged back into the development release. In some cases a patch stays in Wine Staging only for a couple of days, while more difficult feature can also remain for a very long time. Please note that there is never a "full merge of all remaining stuff in Wine Staging" - each feature and bug fix is evaluated separately, and merged if it is suitable for the development branch.

If you want to know what bugs are fixed in Wine Staging, you can take a look at https://bugs.winehq.org/buglist.cgi?bug_status=STAGED